# How to create a data-entry form using COBOL for Windows

Tags: windows, cobol, data-entry

I am using VFP 9 in Windows 7 for my DBMS and want to do this in COBOL for windows.

For a start I want to create, for my Retail Pharmacy,  a Medicines List Table with Medicine Type,Medicine Name,Unit Price and use it as a look-up table for Billing in my Retail Pharmacy.

Then I want to create a Data Entry Form to get general Data like Bill Number, Bill Date, Customer Name.

After that I want to present to the User scrollable Alphabetised Medicine List when called with the first letter of the medicine name by the user with provision to enter quantity required for each required medicine.

After this is over, the COBOL app should calculate Itemwise amount (Unit Rate in Look Up Table multiplied by Quantity entered by the USer and then calculate the Total Bill Amount
and print out a Sales Bill with suitable Header and Footer and also save / add append  the Bill to a file in the program-designated folder in my hard disk.

I am now doing all this with VFP9 in my newer machines running Windows 7 32 & 64 bit and also with MS QBasic v 1.1 and Foxpro for Dos v 2.5 a in my older MS DOS PCs running MS DOS 6.22.

Comment: What do you mean specfically by "COBOL for Windows"?

Comment: Your question is very broad.  It asks for database design, UI elements, and one or more executable programs.  Show us what you have coded so far.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a direct answer to your question - its a bit too open ended for the SO forum. But
let me guess, FoxPro is essentially dead and you need to redevelop your application for a newer platform.

You are not the first person to face this problem.

Rather than redeveloping your application in something
like COBOL on a PC platform, a task that may be rather daunting, why not explore the possibility of
migrating to a differnt product. For example, I believe there are several tools available to help migrate FoxPro to
VB.Net. There is some cost involved here (VB.Net isn't free, nor are the conversion packages).
This approach is not without some problems (you might not get exactly the interface you are accustomed to and
the converted code might not be very well structured or maintainable), but it should be fairly quick and uncomplicated to do.
The down side is that you are simply moving from one vendor solution to another. Single vendor solutions, even
those from large corporations like MicroSoft, sometimes end up being discontinued before you would like.

Another approach might be to redevelop under an open source product. For example, PHP-MySQL-Apache using 
the [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) server instal could be worth exploring. 
This may appear to be overkill for a standalone application but there is plenty of free support for this type of setup. 
I do not recommend that casual developers tinker with the inner workings of complex open source
software such as this - but the popularity and open source aspect ensure it will be operable for several more generations of
whatever operating system you are using.
An additional point is that once you have rebuilt your system under a client-server model it becomes somewhat more
scalable and easier to deploy over a network should you ever want to go that route.

Why not use COBOL? In actual fact there is nothing fundamentally wrong with this approach either. COBOL is very
well suited for developing the type of application you have described. However, COBOL does not provide standard
database or UI components (screen management is defined but often poorly supported). Database and UI tend to be vendor 
specific add ons so you again end up tied to
a single vendor solution. COBOL tends to be more
popular in large mainframe shops so getting good support for COBOL and related tools is difficult outside of 
that environmnent. Try finding a recent college or university graduate in computer science that has knowledge of
COBOL and you will see what I mean. If you want to continue with COBOL, have a look at [Open COBOL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-cobol/)
which is open source and has a reasonably large support community willing to help out small time developers.

My best advice to you is to take time to research and evaluate your conversion/migration strategy before committing to
any one of them. There are many factors at play here, some more obvious than others, but choices you make
right now will have long range consequnces on the success of your application.